# Jessie USB mic in and on-board 3.5mm jack out

Tags: audio

I've had problems with setting Raspbian Jessie as the default USB mic input and default on-board 3.5 mm jack out. I have a USB microphone and would like to use the Raspberry Pi jack audio out. I've read a lot about changing files like:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

but it didn't work for me. My `~/asoundrc` file looks like this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "hw:0,0"
    capture.pcm "hw:1,1"
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think that maybe the file in your home directory should be `.asoundrc` (with a preceding dot)

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble for weeks, and i eventually found it in the asoundrc but ive just typed this in on my new zero and its not there.

However i found an easier way :

> menu
>   preferences
>   audio device settings
>   sound card - then goto drop down menu and you should see your audio device . Select and make default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work. Setting a default will do exactly that, but for both Mic and Audio out. The question was how to set different cards for each. In fact setting a default seems to trigger the behaviour of the system to overwrite ~/.asoundrc on boot, then you will not be able to customise .asoundrc, so its about the worst thing you can do in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
I had a ~/.asoundrc file with following content:

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "hw:0,0"
    capture.pcm "hw:1,0"
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more than just "It works for me".

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with my 3B+ more than [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/67525/68286) or [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/69566/68286).  In case it helps anyone, you can list playback devices with `asound -l` and recording devices with `arecord -l` (those are Ls).  While troubleshooting, don't forget to check to see if anything has overwritten your changes with its own; that's happened to me at least once (probably when I opened the Raspbian audio dialog, though I wouldn't have hit save)...