# How to use USB mic (in) and 3.5 mm audio jack (out)?

Tags: usb, audio

whenever I am making changes my usb becomes default instead of 3.5 mm jack for output.
Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Find your recording and playback devices.

Note the card number and device number for recording.

```
$ arecord -l
```

Note the card number and device number for playback.

```
$ aplay -l
```

Create a new file named .asoundrc in the home directory (/home/pi). Make sure it has the right slave definitions for microphone and speaker:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
```